# charset conversion in mule3 service

Tags: java, character-encoding, jersey, jackson, mule

I have a Jersey service running in a Mule 3 container on Linux using jTDS drivers to connect to MS SQL Server.
The database is CP1252, I want the service to return UTF-8.
Is there a way to define the conversion in configuration, or do I just need to do it explicitly with Java?

Answer (score 1):

Mule uses `UTF-8` as its default encoding, unless specified otherwise via the `mule.encoding` system property at start-up.

So the Jersey service running in Mule should use the same encoding, unless the HTTP request specifies it differently with a `Accept-Charset` header.

Comment: Thank you for the succinct answer, but it doesn't answer my question. Perhaps I wasn't clear.
The service is connecting to a database which is using CP-1252 encoding. I am looking for the appropriate place to do the conversion to UTF-8.

Comment: Why data type are you dealing with? If it's CHAR/VARCHAR, the JDBC driver should convert these to Java's String representation (Unicode), which in term should get encoded to UTF-8 by the service.

Comment: There are 2 fields in question, one VARCHAR and one TEXT. I confirmed the VARCHAR is returning the "unknown character" character. I configured jTDS to use CP1252 by appending ";charset=CP1252" to the connection URL in the spring:property of the dbcp datasource.

Comment: So jTDS is not bringing the correct character over into Java? What unicode character were you expected and which one did you get instead?

Comment: The strings from the database contain the quote characters (147,148) in CP-1252 that do not map to UTF-8. It sounds like I'll just need to explicitly re-encode the strings in my DAO.

Comment: I'm very surprised to hear manual encoding is needed. What's the unicode value (integer) in the Java string coming straight from the DB for this quote character?